# marquee text not display all text

Tags: jquery, html, marquee

I have a marquee text set using jquery:

```
  function abc (){
        var aaa = $("<span />");
        aaa.append("testing1");
        aaa.append("<br/>");
        aaa.append("testing2");
        aaa.append("<br/>");
        aaa.append("testing3");
        aaa.append("<br/>");
        aaa.append("testing4");
        aaa.append("<br/>");
        aaa.append("testing5");
        aaa.append("<br/>");
        aaa.append("testing6");
        aaa.append("<br/>");
        aaa.append("testing7");
        aaa.append("<br/>");
        aaa.append("testing8");
        aaa.append("<br/>");
        $("#faLabel").append(aaa);
  }
```

and here is the html:

```
 <td>
      <marquee direction="up">
          <div id="faLabel"></div>
      </marquee>
 </td>
```

the problem is after I trigger the abc function, the marquee is only display until certain point, not full displaying it all.

but if I just using this tag:

```
  <td>
      <marquee direction="up">
          <div id="faLabel">
             testing1<br/>
             testing2<br/>
             testing3<br/>
             testing4<br/>
             testing5<br/>
             testing6<br/>
             testing7<br/>
             testing8<br/>
          </div>
      </marquee>
 </td>
```

It will display all the text.

How do I display it all using jquery?

Thank You.

Comment: The `<marquee>` tag is obsolete. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee

Comment: I know it, but why if I am not using jquery, the text will display all?

Comment: marguee tag is deprecated, do not use it, it will never work crossbrowser